# Possibilities, to place $n$ distinct balls in an urn $U_i$ so that the number of balls in $U_i$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}(U_i) = \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $U_1,...,U_r$ be distinct urns.

How can one find out for a fixed $i \in [r]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ the number of possibilities, to place $n$ distinct balls in an urn $U_i$ so that the number of balls in $U_i$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}(U_i) = \mathbb{N}$?

$\mathcal{M}(U_i) \subseteq \mathbb{N_0}$. It is just a set for every urn $U$.

I am getting so confused by this question. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{M}(U_i)$? Define it.

Comment: You are right - the question is very confusing!